# magento collection of a model isnt loaded

Tags: php, magento

I want to load a model called Repository in my code. The data is inserted correctly in db by model script, primary key is set to 'repository_id'. However, I am not able to read my data, so I might have a problem but I don't see where.
Call :

```
 $repos = Mage::getModel('Module/repository')->getCollection();
    var_dump($repos); // bool false
    $repos = Mage::getResourceModel('Module/repository_collection');
    var_dump($repos); // bool false

        $repos = Mage::getModel('Module/repository')->getResourceCollection(); // error Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/Module/repository" already exists
        var_dump($repos);
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Mysql4/Resource/Repository/Collection.php

```
class Company_Module_Model_Resource_Repository_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Module/repository');
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Mysql4/Resource/Repository.php

```
class Company_Module_Model_Resource_Repository extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Module/repository', 'repository_id');
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Repository.php

```
class Company_Module_Model_Repository extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Module/repository');
    }


}
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>company_module_resource</resourceModel>
            </Module>
            <company_module_resource>
                <class>Company_Module_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <repository>
                        <table>company_repository</table>
                    </repository>
                </entities>
            </company_module_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Edit : I forgot to mention that i am on magento 1.4, thats why i use mysql4 ressources.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot **Mysql4** in you classes names.
Config:

```
        <company_module_resource>
            <class>Company_Module_Model_Mysql4_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <repository>
                    <table>company_repository</table>
                </repository>
            </entities>
        </company_module_resource>
```

Models:

```
    Company_Module_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Repository_Collection
    Company_Module_Model_Mysql4_Resource_Repository
```

Comment: I don't know how my alias was in fault, i was extending a mysql4 class but it works. Thanks